# The set of points at which a real function is continuous is borel?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

$f: \mathbb D(f) \subset \mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R$. I have to prove that $\mathcal C_f = \{x\in \mathbb R : \text{ f is continuous at } x\}$ is a Borel set. So I define 
$A_n=\{x∈\mathbb R:\exists \delta>0 \text{ such that }∀x_1,x_2 \in (x-\delta, x+\delta)(∣f(x_1)−f(x_2)∣<1 / n)\}$ 
and I plan to show that $A = \cap_{n \in \mathbb N}A_n$ is equal to  $\mathbb C_f $.

I know that each $A_n$ is open, so $A$ is Borel. I also proved that $A \subset \mathbb C_f$. I am stuck in trying to prove that $\mathbb C_f \subset A$. Let $x$ in $\mathbb C_f$. Then there is a $\delta > 0$ such that $x_0 \in \mathbb D(f) \cap (a-\delta,a+\delta) \Rightarrow |f(x_0) - f(x)| < 1/2n$. Then I would take $x_1, x_2$ for this $\delta$, use the triangle inequality and be done. But my problem is, that this is not true for all $x_1, x_2$. By the definition of continuity, the function must be defined on them. Generally, there might be $x'$'s in $(a-\delta, a+\delta)$ for which $f$ is not defined.

For example, if $f$ is continuous on $[1,2]$, then $f$ is continuous at $1$, but $1 \not\in A_n$. Is there a way to bypass this problem?

EDIT: Corrected the domain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define
$$
f_{\ast}(x) = \sup_{\epsilon > 0} \inf_{|y-x|<\epsilon} f(y)
$$
Then, I claim that for any $p\in \mathbb{Q}$,
$$
S_p = \{x : f_{\ast}(x) > p\}
$$
is open.

Proof : Suppose $x_0 \in S_p$, then there is $\epsilon > 0$ such that
$$
\inf_{|y-x_0|<\epsilon} f(y) > p
$$
Then, for any $x$ such that $|x-x_0| < \epsilon$, choose $\epsilon'$ such that
$$
(x-\epsilon',x+\epsilon') \subset (x_0-\epsilon, x_0+\epsilon)
$$
Then
$$
\inf_{|y-x|<\epsilon'}f(y) > p \Rightarrow f_{\ast}(x) > p
$$
Hence, $S_p$ is open.

---

Now, define
$$
f^{\ast}(x) = \inf_{\epsilon > }\sup_{|y-x|<\epsilon}f(y)
$$
Then, $f^{\ast} = -(-f)_{\ast}$, so a similar fact is true for $f^{\ast}$.

---

Now note that the set of discontinuities of $f$ is
$$
D = \{ x : f_{\ast}(x) < f^{\ast}(x)\}
$$
$$
= \{x : \exists p, q \in \mathbb{Q} : f_{\ast}(x) \leq p < q \leq f^{\ast}(x)\}
$$
$$
= \bigcup_{p,q\in\mathbb{Q}, p<q} (\{x: f_{\ast}(x) \leq p\}\cap \{x : f^{\ast}(x) \geq q\})
$$
Hence, $D$ is borel, so $D^c$ is Borel (in fact, a $G_{\delta}$ set)

Answer (score 0):

In general $\mathcal C_f$ is not a Borel set. For example, let $\phi$ be the Cantor-Lebesgue function that is an increasing continuous function from $[0,1]$ onto $[0,1]$. Now define the function $\psi: [0,1]\rightarrow [0,2]$ with $\psi(x)=\phi(x)+x$, where it is a strictly increasing continuous function that maps $[0,1]$ onto $[0,2]$. Then there exists a measurable set $A$ subset of the Cantor set
such that $\psi(A)$ is a nonmeasurable set. Now if the function $f$ is identity map on $\psi(A)$, then $\mathcal C_f=\psi(A)$, where its a nonmeasurable set.

Comment: The domain of your function is not $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: I know, I think if domain of $f$ is convex set, then $\mathcal C_f$ is Borel set.

Comment: The set of discontinuities of an increasing (nondecreasing) function is at most countable. (An increasing function can have only jump discontinuities, and the total height of the jumps in any compact interval contained in the domain is finite.

Comment: @PrahladVaidyanathan I didn't mean that the domain was $\mathbb R$, my mistake.