# suppose $ f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is M-measurable, Let E be the set of points at which f is continuous, show that E is M-measurable.

Tags: measure-theory, measurable-functions

I know that if f is M-measurable, that for any open set U, $f^{-1} (U)$ is M-measurable, so I tried to show the value of the set is union of open sets but then I realized that is not true for example $f(x) = x^2$ when x is rational, 0 otherwise, then the set only contains 0.
And I saw a similar questions [The set of points at which a real function is continuous is borel?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/513339/the-set-of-points-at-which-a-real-function-is-continuous-is-borel), but here I have o show $S_p$ is M-measurable instead of open, and I could not figure out how to do that.

Comment: What's $M$? The Lebesgue $\sigma$-algebra? In that case, even without measurability, the set of continuity points is always $G_\delta$ (hence Borel) as one can prove explicitly by playing with quantifiers.

Comment: I think it is not mean L-measurable, and L-measurable is one case, it can be anything as defined if f is M-measurable, then for any open set the preimage is M-measurable